# Sql query to select the values and group them by Series

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on an sql server 2008 database.

I have a table like this"

```
Id     Year    Series  Value
----+------+--------+------
1     1990    a       1.5
1     1990    b       1.6
1     1990    c       1.7
1     1991    a       1.8
1     1991    b       1.9
1     1991    c       2.5
```

Is there a query that can select the values and return them like this?

```
Year    a     b        c
------+------+--------+------
1990    1.5    1.6      1.7
1991    1.8    1.9      2.5
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Are the series values (a,b,c) a fixed set or can `Series` take on additional values?

Comment: There might be other series but i am only interested in a, b and c so yeah we can consider them fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If series is fixed to a,b,c you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (Id    INT,  Year  INT,  
    Series VARCHAR(5), Value DECIMAL(10,1))
INSERT #t
VALUES
(1,     1990,    'a',       1.5),
(1,     1990,    'b',       1.6),
(1,     1990,    'c',       1.7),
(1,     1991,    'a',       1.8),
(1,     1991,    'b',       1.9),
(1,     1991,    'c',       2.5)

SELECT  pvt.Year,
        pvt.a,
        pvt.b,
        pvt.c
FROM    #t
PIVOT (
    MIN(Value) FOR Series IN ([a], [b], [c])
) pvt
```

If there would be other values you can use dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @series VARCHAR(100) = 
    STUFF(( SELECT  DISTINCT ',[' + Series + ']'
            FROM    #t
            FOR     XML PATH(''))
            ,1, 1, '')

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000) = '
SELECT  pvt.Year, ' + @series +'
FROM    #t
PIVOT (
    MIN(Value) FOR Series IN (' + @series + ')
) pvt
';

EXEC(@query)
```

In a scenario with fixed series, there is also possibility with CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT  a.Year, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN a.Series = 'a' THEN a.Value END) a,
        MAX(CASE WHEN a.Series = 'b' THEN a.Value END) b,
        MAX(CASE WHEN a.Series = 'c' THEN a.Value END) c
FROM    #t a
CROSS   JOIN #t b
GROUP   BY a.Id, a.Year
ORDER   BY a.Year
```